# How solution bug with last slide animation in Slick Slider

Tags: javascript, css-transitions, slick.js

I need to help with Slick slider.
The transition from the last slide to the first is very abrupt. You can see it in this Gif:

[image: Transform transform(0px 90px) to transform(0px 0px) without transition in last slide.]

Transform transform(0px 90px) to transform(0px 0px) without transition in last slide.

`$('#slick-slider').slick({
  infinite: true,
  slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  swipe: true,
  arrows: true,
  // swipeToSlide: true,
  focusOnSelect: true,
  centerMode: false
});
body {
  background-color: black;
}

#slick-slider {
  padding: 0 50px;
}

.slick-prev {
  left: 15px!important;
}

.slick-next {
  right: 15px!important;
}

.slide {
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.inner-block {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  transform: translate(0px, 50px);
  transition: all 500ms ease;
}

.slide:hover .inner-block,
.slide.slick-current .inner-block {
  transform: translate(0px, 0px);
}
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.js"></script>

<div id="slick-slider">
  <div class="slide">
    <div class="inner-block"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <div class="inner-block"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <div class="inner-block"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <div class="inner-block"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <div class="inner-block"></div>
  </div>
</div>`

I'm try use CSS animation with transitions but it not working correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Check this code

```
.slick-slide .inner-block,
.slick-slide[aria-hidden=true]:not(.slick-cloned) ~ .slick-cloned[aria-hidden=true] .inner-block {
    height: 100px;
    background-color: green;
    transform: translate(0px, 50px);
    transition: all 500ms ease;
}
.slick-center .inner-block,
.slick-slide[aria-hidden=true]:not([tabindex="-1"]) + .slick-cloned[aria-hidden=true] .inner-block {
    transform: translate(0px, 0px);
}
```

or check this link,

https://codepen.io/rabbularafat/pen/PoxNpvm